# PHP, getting $value out of a specific $key in associative multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I'm quite new with PHP and I'm facing a problem with arrays.
say I have a multidimensional associative array called $charsarray like this:

```
[1] => ([name] => mickey [surname] => mouse)
[2] => ([name] => donald [surname] => duck)
...
[N] => (...)
```

I need to extract the "surname" field of each entry so my code has nested foreach:

```
foreach($charsarray as $key => $value )
{
    foreach($value => $singlechar)
    {
      echo $singlechar
    }
}
```

This outputs both **mickey** **mouse** **donald** **duck** since these are the values of the associative array.

If I want to extract only surnames I could write an if statement to check against the key surname.

Is there a better approach to this without using the if statement ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the entire thing. You can just reference the specific value in the array by using correct index (surname).

```
foreach($charsarray as $key => $value )
{
   echo $value['surname']

}
```

Comment: Damn ! I was doing the same but INSIDE the second foreach loop, so I was getting the first char of each entry only: MMDD . Now I got it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Surname also a key in that array so you need to print like as below

```
foreach($charsarray as $key => $val){
   echo $val['surname'];
}
```